# Detecting a sequence of mouse movements

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouse, detection, classification

In ActionScript 3, I need to detect a sequence of movements made by the mouse when the button is down.
I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891808/algorithm-to-recognise-mouse-movements), and it seems a bit overkill. I only need to detect the 8 basic directions (up/down/left/right/diagonals), so that I can detect a "Z".

Are you aware of any free/open-source solutions? How would you do that otherwise? I've already implemented a few classification algorithms, but I'm looking for something really basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on how to do exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/07/05/detecting-mouse-gestures-in-flash-with-as3/

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code for https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firegestures/ which is open source under the Mozilla Public License 1.1.

Basically it waits until you've moved a certain distance from the last point to create a new point, and detects the angle in between.  If the direction has changed, it adds it to your list of moves, so "Z" would be R,DL,R.

Comment: Note the question was "in actionscript 3". :)

Comment: @Ascension Note that the differences in AS3 and JavaScript don't change the algorithm.

Comment: That is a good point and I would remove my downvote but it's locked in. If you edit the question, maybe throw in your point, it'll allow me to remove my downvote and I'll trade it in for an upvote. :)

Comment: I'll give you my upvote, but I still prefer the AS3 version above :)